# How to join two tables, each table from a different database, inside a view in Snowflake when database names contain environment prefix

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-view

I have databases with the below naming convention per environment (created within one Snowflake account) as below:

ENV_DWH  (DEV_DWH, UAT_DWH, PROD_DWH and so on) -- This is the database that contains the Data warehouse tables.

ENV_STG_SRC1  (DEV_STG_SRC1, UAT_STG_SRC1 and so on)  -- This is the staging database that contains the stage tables for source 1.

I am trying to create a database view inside DEV_DWH database which joins some tables from this database and one other table from the STG database, like below.

```sql
Create view Dim.vwTest 
As
Select dimTb1.Col1, stgTbl.Col2
From Dim.Table1 dimTb1
Inner Join DEV_STG_SRC1.StgTable1 stgTbl
ON dimTbl.Col1 = stgTbl.Col1;
```

How can I generalize the stage database name reference(somehow replace the hard coded database name with the environment prefix in it) in this script, so that it can run in each corresponding environment without the need to maintain multiple versions of script files each per environment?

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any tool or the WebUI of Snowflake?

Comment: I am using Web UI